# Relationship between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compatibility

When Stroustroup was designing C++, one of his goals was that C++ were as much a superset of C as possible. I understand that this is not 100% the case, but most of good code in C is also C++ code.

But I am hearing that C99 supports many things that C++ doesn't (like VLA) and that there is even going to be C1x or C0x whatever it's called. So, C++ is a superset of only ***old*** C89 and from then on C and C++ are developing pretty much independently?

Comment: [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) is the next C++ version.

Comment: @Armen: that's what they say ;-) edit: I thought you meant C++0x when you mentioned 'C1x' or 'C0x'.

Comment: @darioo: by C0x or C1x I meant the next version of C, not C++ :)

Comment: C0x would probably be interpreted as ISO/IEC TR 18037:2004. The (plans for a) successor to C99 are known as C1x.

Comment: Most good C code does **not** compile as C++. If you're using proper C idioms, you have to go out of your way and make them ugly in order for them to compile as C++. The most obvious example is simply any use of `malloc`.

Comment: @R: That is really true for ANSI C, but not for K&R C which is really the common ancestor of both C++ and ANSI C.

Comment: The term "ANSI C" is misleading and misunderstood. Better not to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ is a near superset of C89/C90.  (I don't recommend writing the code with the purpose of being able to compile it as either C or C++, though.)  Since then, C99 diverged.  The new C++ standard (often called C++0x) will have some attempt to be more compatible, but isn't going to have such things as the C99 variable-length arrays.  Stroustrup has expressed disappointment with some of the C committee's actions, apparently having expected them to try to keep closer to C++ compatibility.

So, yes, the languages are diverging.

Comment: +1 for "near superset", C is weakly typed while C++ type-system isn't as permissive.

Comment: @MSalters:  Said not entirely correctly, in my opinion.  `int * foo = malloc(42 * sizeof(int));` is proper C, but won't compile in C++.  Adding the `(int *)` cast to the `malloc` makes it compile in C++, but the only thing it does in C is cover up if you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`.  Since I ran into that case, I've been an advocate of knowing whether you're writing C or C++, and not restricting oneself to the common subset.  It is true that the worse C constructs tend not to work in C++.

Comment: even better if you replace `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof *foo`, and this also illustrates an important reason *not* to cast the return value (then the code breaks if you change types).

Comment: @R.:  Thank you, I haven't programmed in C for some time, and it shows.  Your allocation is better, and your reason for omitting the cast is better.

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. C++ started off as a superset of C when it was originally developed. Since that time, the two have grown independent of the other.

Comment: I'm not sure that C++ was ever a strict superset of any version of C. Certainly the first C++ standard was not 100% C-compatible.

Comment: @Marcelo:  Stroustrup's "Design and Evolution of C++" mentions that the 1980 C with Classes wasn't completely compatible with C, as `int class;` was fine C and illegal C with Classes.  The evolution into C++ introduced more incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4):

There is a concerted effort to keep the languages as compatible as is practicable, and C++0x will adopt some of C99's changes. But it does seem likely that they will diverge to some extent, with VLAs being the most notable discrepancy. I don't know that C++ will adopt `restrict` either.

Comment: The next C++ standard is nearly done, and there will be no feature additions.  Since this is the standard that would incorporate C99 compatibility features, I'd say they're moving away.

Comment: @David: Are you disagreeing with something I wrote?

Comment: Nitpicking, I guess. You said it seems likely that they'd diverge; I'm saying that in practice they've already diverged.

Comment: @David: Perhaps my phrasing was a little lazy. I mean it in the sense of, "will establish a long-term pattern of divergence." Even programming-language standards aren't fixed forever, and there is a small chance that C++ will eventually adopt many of the C99 features it eschewed this time around, if for no other reason than to reclaim some lost compatibility, if that proves important (and painful) enough. Also, the question was whether the languages are "developing pretty much independently". To simply say that they are diverging doesn't tell the full story.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting article by Bjarne Stroustrup that sheds some light on the topic: [Sibling Rivalry: C and C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/sibling_rivalry.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Gah. He insists on abusing "equality" in the languages to rally support.

Answer (score 2):

> but most of good code in C is also C++ code.

No.

I would say that most good C code is compilable using a C++ compiler.
That does not make it C++ code.

> C++ is a superset of only old C89 and from then on C and C++ are developing pretty much independently?

C++ was based of C89.
C was extended with C99 very little of which was incorporated into C++03
There are ongoing efforts to minimize the difference and bring the languages closer (where it is reasonable) for C++0x

Comment: The saying claims that "good C code is also C++ code", not that "good C code is also *good* C++ code".  But yes, this is an important difference.

Answer (score 1):

Even for old C, aka C89, under the hood the difference is difficult to handle, returns from operators that are lvalue for one and not the other, control flow that is valid for one and not the other etc. Where they are ok is on an interface level for functions with prototypes, `struct` etc.

For newer version of the languages this diverges even more, since even interface compatibility might be difficult to maintain. C99 already has the `static` keyword for bounds of array function parameters, the concepts of compile time constants are quite different in both languages, C++ starts reusing old keywords (`auto`) and excessively uses new keywords that are not in a reserved namespace...

So yes, I think the divide will grow, and it would probably better for both communities to admit the divorce and to try to get along separately.

Comment: I think both have already "admitted" the divorce, but they still try to get along as much as possible, which seems like a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @jalf: They need to be broken. The amusing thing is if you take the C out of C++, it only leaves an excessively complicated nightmare language from the 80s. Even so, given a few more updates, and dropping the ridiculous C compatibility sham, and removing all the archaic syntax and boilerplate, C++ might actually be a decent language. I don't see this being feasible.