# What is the relationship between C and C++ (more technical approach)

Tags: c++, c, relationship, libraries

I was reading through [Relationship between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388606/relationship-between-c-and-c) and was interested in a more technical look at the question.

For example, if you want to use threads in C++, would you (assuming a Linux platform) just use pthreads? I know C++ has the STL and the Boost libraries fill in a lot of gaps... but do C++ programmers generally use libraries for C code?

I'm trying to decide if it's worth learning C++ as I already know C (admittedly learning C is not a pre-requisite and can be a disadvantage) but I'm not sure how C++ and C libraries etc all tie in together....

Comment: Give both C and C++ up and learn D instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up through C++03, yes, you'd probably use pthreads. The current draft of C++11 has threading built into the standard library, so you'd probably use that instead (though it's based closely on pthreads, so there's little practical difference between them).

In general, however, yes, it's easy to use C libraries directly from C++, and in the absence of a C++ library for the purpose it's common to use them. For that matter, even when there is a C++ library, some people sometimes prefer to use C libraries anyway.

Comment: That is a decision to be taken, I have rarely used `pthreads` in C++03 code, but rather `boost::thread`, `ACE` tasks or `QThread`... all of which (as C++0x threads) might use `pthread` underneath in POSIX systems, or other implementations in non-POSIX environments. I would not go as far as saying that with C++03 people use pthreads, some have some haven't.

Comment: Even before `boost::thread`, you wouldn't use raw pthreads in C++; you'd write your own library to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 2):

C libraries are used in C++ constantly. Sometimes they get wrapped in a nicer idiomatic C++ interface, sometimes not. Lots of thin C++ wrappers around C socket APIs, for example, but people often use sockets directly anyway. I directly use various POSIX functions in C++ all the time.

You do need to make sure you already understand C, though (the number of new C++ programmers who try to pass C++ strings directly to C functions expecting C-strings...). And it takes time to learn the best ways to do certain things (that C function that needs a pointer to an array of data? Just give it the address of the first element of your C++ vector, don't manually allocate/build a new array).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just concerned with interoperability of C and C++ library.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

is a pretty good link.

If you have never done objected oriented programming, I would recommended giving C++ a try. Both are Turing complete language, There is nothing C++ cannot do that C already can't.

Comment: It's not so much interoperability, but more how C++ is used. Obviously there are a tonne of C libraries floating about, and many aren't available for C++... so I was wondering how much C (or at least C libraries) to C++ programmers actually use?

Comment: @PeterM Personally I only use a c library if there is no equivalent C++ choice. I was about to say libjpeg as an example and I just searched and found that there is a jpegxx now.