# accessing arrays that are a member of a class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have a c++ class that has a private array member.

```
class array_test
{
public:
    std::tuple<double*, int> get_vector_member();

private:
    double test_array[3];
};
```

In C++11 is there a better method call to get a double[] that doesn't involve grabbing double as a pointer. I am worried that either myself or someone else will delete the pointer and cause some strange undefined behavior.

I hope the fact I didn't include an implementation for get_vector_member is an issue.

Comment: What is the second element in the `tuple`? Is it the array length? If so, use `std::array<double, 3> test_array;` and have `get_vector_member()` return a `std::array<double, 3>&` (or `std::array<double, 3> const&`).

Comment: Technically speaking, that isn't a C++ array. It's a C-style array. So, no, C++ isn't going to start modifying C-style array behavior, if that's your question. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) s a C++ array.

Comment: @ParthianShot: That's nonsense. C++ has [array types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array).

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not saying it won't work, I'm just saying that C++ is a superset of C, and if you're worried about using C versions of things, then use the functionality written into C++ to replace the C functionality. In the same way that "hello world" is a C-style string, and if you don't want to work with `const char *` you can use the C++ `string` type. It's a bad habit; it's like using `printf` when `cout <<` exists.

Comment: @ParthianShot: C++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: @KerrekSB To within a fair approximations, for a lot of programs, [yes, it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388606/relationship-between-c-and-c). The two are diverging, but there are a lot of features in C++ that **would not be there at all** (because they are duplicate functionality) if it weren't for the desire of source-compatibility with C. That was one of the original goals of the language. The point is that plenty of C features exist in C++, but it is good coding style to carefully remember what language you're in. Would you at least agree the similarities are more than cosmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about providing typical C++ field accessor functions, with a const and non-const overload, returning a reference to the field?

```
class X
{
    double data[3];

public:
    // Accessors
    double (&get())[3] { return data; }
    const double (&get() const)[3] { return data; }
};
```

In C++14 this code is a bit easier to write:

```
auto & get() { return data; }
const auto & get() const { return data; }
```

Comment: cool, but whats up with &get() in parenthesis? Also, why can't you use auto& in c++11, since c++11 also has auto&?

Comment: @ZacharyKraus: What do you mean with "what's up"? That's how you write types in C++ (the return type is `double(&)[3]`). Unfortunately, the type syntax is a bit insane, but that's largely C's fault. Use c++decl if in doubt. C++11 doesn't have return type deduction for normal functions, that's new in C++14.

Comment: But why is both the & and get() inside the parenthesis? I know the & has to be there because of double(&)[3]. Yeah the syntax is really whacky. In fact it was so whacky in my actual project i just used a vector constructed to be size 3.

Comment: @ZacharyKraus For precedence reasons. Without the parentheses, `get` would be interpreted as a function returning an array of 3 references to double.

Comment: @ZacharyKraus: You can use typedefs to make your life easier: `using T = double[3]; T foo; T & get_foo() { return foo; }`. Same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Some reasons why they're superior to raw arrays:

- Easy element access with the [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/front) and [`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/back) member functions.
- They're copy constructible and assignable.
- Optional [bounds-checked access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).
- Cool [comparison operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) like `==`, `!=` and `<`.
- The [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) member function.
- No weird syntax when passing by reference.

Then return that by reference:

```
class array_test
{
public:
    const std::array<double, 3>& get_array_member() const;

private:
    std::array<double, 3> test_array;
};
```